# if statement going through both ways

Tags: android

Okay I've got this method which ends like this:

```
if(totalDeg > mStartAngle && totalDeg < mSweepAngle){
            return true;
        }
        else {
            return false;
        }
```

Odd thing is, when debugging on step-by-step, I stop at `return true`, press F6 (or F5) on Eclipse, then the next instruction is `return false`!!!

How is this even possible?

PD. this is where I call this function:

```
if(d.isInArea(x, y)){
            //d.onTap();
            Toast.makeText(mContext, "Directory " + d.getName() + " was tapped!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}
```

and this is the isInArea method:

```
public boolean isInArea(float x, float y){
        int deltaX = (int) (x - mRectShape.centerX());
        int deltaY = (int) (y - mRectShape.centerY());

        if (Math.sqrt(Math.pow(deltaX, 2) + Math.pow(deltaY, 2)) > mRectShape.width()/2) {
            return false;
        }

        double offset = 0;

        //now calculate angle
        double angle = Math.atan2(deltaY, deltaX);
        double total = angle;
        double totalDeg = Math.toDegrees(total);
        Log.d(LOG_TAG, "angle :" + totalDeg);

        if(totalDeg > mStartAngle && totalDeg < mSweepAngle){
            return true;
        }
        else {
            return false;
        }
    }
```

Comment: well, which value is returned actually? the correct one?

Comment: no, it should return true (in fact, it only enters the return true if the condition is met), but it is returning false

Comment: Show the method that calls this one?

Comment: You most likely do not debug the correct version of the code. The debugger is reporting some lines, and Eclipse highlights them on different code, making it seem like you're passing through both branches of if/else at the same time. Add some print or log statements to each branch (as well as before the if , to display the arguments) this will tell you exactly what's happening.

Comment: @Geobits posted a bit more code

Comment: @Shivan Dragon so how do I fix it? I cleaned the project and restarted Eclipse to no avail. Also I am getting the wrong result.

Comment: @kelmer make sure you have the right code sources in Eclipse (in correspondance to those that resulted in the program deployed on your Android device). Does the code have several versions, if so try getting the same version for the (compiled) app and the sources and retry to debug. Can you build the sources you already have and use THAT as the app-to-be-deployed-and-debugged?

Comment: Did you try deleting the app from device and debug a new build? Alsp are you callin d.isInArea(x,y) in some loop?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, as you alluded to- this isn't possible. I suspect this is to do with one of two things; (1) the code that *looks* like it's being run in the IDE isn't the *actual* code being run - i.e. the generated dex files after a project build have got out of sync with the src or (2) the single line declaration of the statement has confused something - it would confuse me! Write the if-statement like so;

```
boolean withinAcceptedAngle;
if(totalDeg > mStartAngle && totalDeg < mSweepAngle) { 
  withinAcceptedAngle = true; 
}
return withinAcceptedAngle;
```

...then do a *Project Clean*, *Project Build* and then re-run with the break point on the return. Note that the `boolean` primitive type is initialised to `false` hence why you don't need to declare it as so. That said, after you find out the reason for the discrepancy you could shorten your code by writing;

```
return totalDeg > mStartAngle && totalDeg < mSweepAngle;
```

The shortening is more of stylistic thing in this case I think. Generally though I prefer the shorthand approach.